# angularJS set today to input date

Tags: angularjs, date, input, angular-ngmodel

I had been trying to set the date to a input type="date" using angular's ng-model and value with no success. I tryed to use the documentation of angular JS about the input-date and the only thing I got was to set the year of the input, day and month remained with the placeholder value: "dd/mm/2014".

what I tried:

```
$scope.value = new Date(2013, 9, 22);
```

and in my HTML:

```
<input type="date" id="exampleInput" name="input" ng-model="value" placeholder="yyyy-MM-dd" min="2013-01-01" max="2013-12-31" required />
```

and what I get is tha input date with: "dd/mm/2013"

I tried using the angular documentation example to be sure that I am doing it right, thats because of the min and max value of the date.

Any idea on how to fill my input date with the date of today ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: true, I Used the solution from that post, works fine. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

```
$scope.value = new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0]; // 2014-05-23
```

tested in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

The date format needs to be in a valid [ISO-8601 date format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (yyyy-MM-dd)

```
// This won't work
new Date(2013, 9, 22); // Tue Oct 22 2013 00:00:00 GMT+1100 (EST)
```

try this:

```
new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0]; // "2014-09-30"
```

Note: `toISOString()` will return the UTC timezone.

See: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bdate%5D

Comment: how i can get Indian time zone date

Answer (score 0):

The above answers generate "Error: ngModel:datefmt
Model is not a date object", at least in angular 1.4.7.

A slight adjustment fixes it:

```
    $scope.value = new Date(new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

I am doing following things,and date get started appearing in mm/dd/yyyy format-

```
<input type="date" data-ng-model="value"  />
```

also do this in controller:

```
$scope.value=new Date();
$scope.value =new Date($scope.value).toISOString().split("T")[0];
```